# How to take any number of arguments from the user and pass them to a method which uses varargs( variable argument )?

Tags: java

I want to take any number of input from the user, and then do their summation as a final product. Infact I am using Varargs in method called sum to take any number of input from the user, but my problem is to how to take that input from the user and pass them as the argument for the method sum.

```
public class calculator 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      BasicFunc obj = new BasicFunc();
      int result = obj.sum(); // here i want user to input any number of 
                              // arguments.
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}

class BasicFunc
{   
   int sum(int...x) // i have used here varargs
   {
        sum = 0;
        for(int a=0 ; a<x.length ; a++) sum += x[a];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: See Scanner java class, use some character, that if user enters it, break the for and pass data to your method

Comment: read values into a list, create an array of the list values and pass the 1 array to the method (varargs also accept ONE array if correct type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] nums = br.readLine().split(" "); //delimitation by space or comma
```

Since you are using int variable arguments you need to create int array before passing it to sum function.

```
int[] numbers = new int[nums.length];
for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++){
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
}
BasicFunc obj = new BasicFunc();
int result = obj.sum(numbers);
```

Remeber to throw Exception while using BufferedReader statement.
References:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-bufferedreader-class

Comment: Thanks Kislay Srivastav, buddy instead of BufferedReader I used Scanner class but your split method was exactly what I was looking for....